# Pseudo Element with React Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I've looked up several answers, and feel like I'm setting this up the exact same way, yet it's not working.

The index.css of my document sets up a gradient background, that works perfectly. Then I have my footer, and that is also working.  But the issue comes where I want to add an SVG as a background to the footer, and set the opacity on it.

If I do this, the background image appears, but the entire footer is affected by the opacity, which of course is a bad result.

```
const Foot = styled.footer `
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-left: 0em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    color: white;
    background-image: url('/logo.svg');
    opacity: 0.25;
}
`
```

But if I do this, which seems to be to be how it's supposed to work if I want just the background image semi-transparent while the rest of the footer stays opaque, then the background image does not show at all:

```
const Foot = styled.footer `
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-left: 0em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    color: white;
    
     &::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url('/logo.svg');
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.25;
    }
}
`
```

How should I set this up so that the background image is semi-transparent, but the rest of the footer is not?

Here is my footer JSX if that helps:

```
<Foot id="footer-page">
                    <Div>
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 text-center">
                                    <p className="lead">HUMAN RESOURCES SOLUTIONS></p>
                                    <img className="img-fluid" src="/assets/images/wbe-seal.png" alt="certified women owned business seal" />
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 text-center"><p className="lead">FOLLOW US ON <Span orange>SOCIAL MEDIA</Span></p>
                                        <A href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i className="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x px-2"></i></A>
                                        <A href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i className="fab fa-instagram fa-3x px-2"></i></A>
                                        <A href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i className="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x px-2"></i></A>
                                        <A href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><i className="fab fa-twitter-square fa-3x px-2"></i></A>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Div>
                </Foot>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use a single colon (:) where you use the `&::before` pseudo-selector.

Also, if that doesn't work you could try using the `after` pseudo-selector.

```js
const Foot = styled.footer `
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-left: 0em;
    padding-right: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    color: white;
    
    &:before {
      content: "";
      background-image: url('/logo.svg');
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0.25;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I have tired both of those, and neither of those work either.

Comment: @AdamNorton Hmm, maybe could try adding `background-size`, `background-position` attributes also? I am not in a place where I can easily debug the issue.